# Using logical_and to combine numpy masks

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, logical-operators, masked-array

I've seen similar questions asked but I'm still struggling with combining masks.

This is my code:

```
final_mask = ma.array(np.logical_and(a.mask, b.mask))

combined_mask=(ma.array(data, mask=final_mask))
```

`data` is the array I want to put the combined mask on to.

When I plot the combined mask it seems to have ignored the `a.mask` as it returns values much higher than it should. I.e. anything over 200 was previously masked but it returns up to 300 here.

`a.mask` and `b.mask` have already been defined and checked so I think it's the combining that is the problem. They both return integers rather than *true/false* values which is what I'm after.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your talk about `a.mask` being integers, etc., is confusing.  Here's a straight forward example of combining masks

```
In [346]: data = np.arange(12)
In [347]: a = np.ma.masked_less(data, 7)
In [348]: b = np.ma.masked_greater(data,2)
In [349]: mask = np.logical_and(a.mask,b.mask)
In [350]: np.ma.array(data, mask=mask)
Out[350]: 
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 -- -- -- -- 7 8 9 10 11],
             mask = [False False False  True  True  True  True False False False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

I end up masking all values >2 and <7.  `a.mask` is boolean.

With integers, 0's are False, all else True

```
In [352]: np.logical_and([0,1,2,3],[3,2,1,0])
Out[352]: array([False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. It looks like my arguments are correct based on what you have said. It's the output of the combined_mask that has me confused as it should have masked all values over 100 but hasn't.


This is a section of the array I get from the combined_mask:
[ -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  250 250 250 250 250 250 250 250 250 250 250 46 46 66 81 81 78 250 250 250]

Comment: I've fixed this now - turns out I didn't need the first line of code.

combined_mask=ma.array(a.mask, mask=b.mask)